# PHPExcel- remove whole row

Tags: php, phpexcel

I need a solution for upload excel file, where is in Column A list of mail addresses who need to be checked. 
Now I have to remove all Gmail addresses in Column A with a whole row.

I made some code, but it does not remove all Gmail address in the row, I think that script removing every second row who contain Gmail.

Can somebody check it and help me?

Here is my code:

```
// setup columns and rows for loop

$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

//define $results from rows as array
$result = []; 


//loop column A and get values from each row in Array $results

for($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {

$result[] = $sheet->getCell('A' .$row)->getValue(); 

}


//remove gmail adresses in rows

foreach($result as $gmail){

if(preg_match('/gmail.com/', $gmail)) {

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row);

  }

}
```

Comment: The value of `$row` never changes after you've looped through the spreadsheet the first time, so you're always removing the last row, regardless of the row that contained the $gmail value

Comment: You could eliminate your first loop by using the `rangeToArray()` method... `$result=$sheet->rangeToArray('A1:A'.$highestRow);`

Comment: You really need to check rows in reverse order.... if you have gmail entries to remove in rows 1 and 3, then removing row 1 first will cause row 3 to become row 2, row 4 to become row 3, etc.... and then removing row 3 will remove what was originally row 4

Comment: Thank you for answer and help, I am trying to finish it all day, but I am confused now.
When I remove my first loop and try with your code, I can't get Gmail results, as I got in my loop.

 Can you help me with this code and show the example how to get Gmail and remove rows?

I will be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with:

```
//define $results from rows as array
$result = []; 


//loop column A and get values from each row in Array $results

for($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {

$result[] = $sheet->getCell('A' .$row)->getValue(); 

}
```

can be replaced with

```
$result = $sheet->rangeToArray('A1:A'.$highestRow);
```

This will return a 2d array or rows and columns, indexed from 0 for each row; you can feed that to `array column()` to get a simple 1-d array.

```
$result = array_column($sheet->rangeToArray('A1:A'.$highestRow), 0);
```

Then you need to reverse the array, retaining the keys, so that you traverse it from bottom to top:

```
$result = array_reverse($result, true);
```

When you traverse the array, you need to retrieve the key as well as the value, because this will allow you to identify the row number:

```
foreach($result as $reference => $gmail){
    if(preg_match('/gmail.com/', $gmail)) {
        $row = $reference + 1; // adjust the array key to the row number
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that is it. 
Thank you very much, you helped me a lot. Thanks again.